# Conditional formatting numbers in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, conditional-formatting

I have some basic spreadsheet info and I need to compare it to previous quarters. I just want a crosstab or heatmap type visualization showing if we are up or down from previous quarter.

Something like this:

[image]

So leads and closings have increased quarter over quarter so those should be color coded green.  Referrals should be coded green for the first two but code red for Q22018 since the number went down.  Is this possible in Tableau? I played around with a calculated field but I'm not sure how to compare the number to a previous quarter info number and not a set number.

I'd like it to look something like this:

[image]

Adding screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a Table Calculation in Color shelf.
[image]

First create a table calculation as below and drag it to Color. Change the mark type to Square.

[image]

Edit the color like below.(If you do not want to play with the color, you can create a custom calculation to return red or green)

[image]

Comment: Quick follow up.  When I'm doing the table calculations it keeps giving me the change in numbers instead of color coding the actual data.  Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: @EP31121PJ, drag the table calculation to the color, not to text

Comment: Jose: I just revised my original post with screenshot of what I'm seeing.  I'm not sure why it isn't coming out right.